# Failed Setting target to http://127.0.0.1:8181 Cloudfoundry vagrant

Tags: cloud-foundry, vagrant

I've already following instruction from https://github.com/Altoros/cf-vagrant-installer on my Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Then after i execute command bellow :

foreman start

I got log message like bellow :

```
06:25:19 nats.1           | started with pid 29659
06:25:19 warden.1         | started with pid 29667
06:25:19 uaa.1            | started with pid 29672
06:25:19 dir_server.1     | started with pid 29676
06:25:19 file_server.1    | started with pid 29679
06:25:19 dea_ng.1         | started with pid 29682
06:25:19 gorouter.1       | started with pid 29685
06:25:19 cc_ng.1          | started with pid 29688
06:25:19 health_manager.1 | started with pid 29691
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | panic: listen tcp 10.0.2.15:8081: address already in use
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | 
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | goroutine 13 [running]:
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | router/common.(*VcapComponent).ListenAndServe(0xf8400bd1e0, 0x0)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/common/component.go:171 +0x337
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | created by router/common.Register
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/common/component.go:104 +0x52f
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | 
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | github.com/cloudfoundry/gonats.(*Client).AcquireConnection(0xf8400d5550, 0x0, 0x8, 0x4b6077)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/gonats/client.go:236 +0x37
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | github.com/cloudfoundry/gonats.(*subscriptionRegistry).Subscribe(0xf8400d5550, 0xf8400d5b90, 0x4bc7c9, 0xf8400d5b90)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/gonats/client.go:182 +0x29
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | github.com/cloudfoundry/gonats.(*Subscription).Subscribe(0xf8400d5b90, 0x6b2b34)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/gonats/client.go:62 +0x2d
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | router/common.Register(0xf8400bd1e0, 0xf8400d5550, 0x686934, 0x756f722f00000007)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/common/component.go:108 +0x58c
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | router.NewRouter(0xf8400a0b40, 0x13, 0xf8400a0b40, 0xf8400a0b40)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/router.go:75 +0x537
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | main.main()
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/router/main.go:25 +0x64
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | 
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | goroutine 2 [syscall]:
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | created by runtime.main
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | 
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | goroutine 3 [syscall]:
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | syscall.Syscall6()
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /usr/local/go/src/pkg/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s:40 +0x5
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | syscall.EpollWait(0xf800000006, 0xf8400cb0c0, 0xa0000000a, 0xffffffff, 0xc, ...)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /usr/local/go/src/pkg/syscall/zerrors_linux_amd64.go:1846 +0xa1
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | net.(*pollster).WaitFD(0xf8400cb0b0, 0xf8400c51c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
06:25:21 gorouter.1       |     /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/fd_linux.go:146 +0x110
06:25:21 gorouter.1       | exited with code 2
06:25:21 system           | sending SIGTERM to all processes
06:25:21                  | net.(*pollServer).Run(0xf8400c51c0, 0x0)
06:25:21                  |     /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/fd.go:236 +0xe4
06:25:21                  | created by net.newPollServer
06:25:21                  |     /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/newpollserver.go:35 +0x382
06:25:21                  | 
06:25:21                  | goroutine 4 [running]:
06:25:21                  | router._func_009(0xf84009b858, 0xf8400d7400, 0xf8400d7410, 0xf8400d7420, 0x0, ...)
06:25:21                  |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/router.go:237
06:25:21                  | created by router.(*Router).establishNATS
06:25:21                  |     /vagrant/gorouter/src/router/router.go:237 +0xff
06:25:21 nats.1           | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 warden.1         | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 uaa.1            | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 dir_server.1     | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 file_server.1    | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 dea_ng.1         | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 cc_ng.1          | terminated by SIGTERM
06:25:21 health_manager.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

I don't know wether above log is error or success, but when execute command bellow :

$ sudo rake cf:init_cf_cli

i got log message like bellow :

```
==> Initializing cf CLI
Setting target to http://127.0.0.1:8181... FAILED
Target refused connection.
target: https://api.run.pivotal.io

Authenticating... FAILED
Password>
```

Anyone know how to solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: That log does not indicate success.  gorouter failed to start because of a port conflict.

Answer (score 0):

visit https://github.com/Altoros/cf-vagrant-installer/issues/55
you should try this
it mentioned about Editing /vagrant/custom_config_files/cloud_controller_ng/cloud_controller.yml and adding a nats_uri key that matches message_bus_uri fixes the issue.